# How to hide search view in action bar

Tags: android, menuitem, searchview

My app has 3 tabs  and tab3 menu items are different.
So what I have done is I have inflated menu items in activity and based on the fragment menuitems visibilty is set.

Activity Code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_page, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Menu_home_page.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_plan_your_day"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_18dp"
    android:title="@string/action_notify"
    android:visible="false"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_notification"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_white_18dp"
    android:title="@string/action_notify"
    android:visible="false"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    android:visible="false"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />


</menu>
```

Tab1 (Fragment Code):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
       getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        final MenuItem contactsSearchMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
        final MenuItem planYourDayMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_plan_your_day);
        final MenuItem notificationMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_notification);
        contactsSearchMenu.setVisible(false);
        planYourDayMenu.setVisible(true);
        notificationMenu.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Tab2 code same like Tab1

Tab3 Code:

```
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        if (menu != null) {
            final MenuItem contactsSearchMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
            final MenuItem planYourDayMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_plan_your_day);
            final MenuItem notificationMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_notification);
            contactsSearchMenu.setVisible(true);
            planYourDayMenu.setVisible(false);
            notificationMenu.setVisible(false);
        }

    }


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    // Locate the search item
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);


    // In version 3.0 and later, sets up and configures the ActionBar SearchView
    if (Utils.hasHoneycomb()) {

        // Retrieves the system search manager service
        final SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String queryText) {

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                String newFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;
                if (mSearchTerm == null && newFilter == null) {
                    return true;
                }


                if (mSearchTerm != null && mSearchTerm.equals(newFilter)) {
                    return true;
                }

                mSearchTerm = newFilter;

                mSearchQueryChanged = true;
                getLoaderManager().restartLoader(
                        ContactsQuery.QUERY_ID, null, ContactsListFragment.this);
                return true;
            }
        });

        if (Utils.hasICS()) {
            MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {

                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {

                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearchTerm)) {
                        onSelectionCleared();
                    }
                    mSearchTerm = null;
                    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(
                            ContactsQuery.QUERY_ID, null, ContactsListFragment.this);
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }

        if (mSearchTerm != null) {
            final String savedSearchTerm = mSearchTerm;

            if (Utils.hasICS()) {
                searchItem.expandActionView();
            }
            searchView.setQuery(savedSearchTerm, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/HomePageAppbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/HomePageTab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/HomePageViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</LinearLayout>
```

But the problem is only searchview menu item is visible for all three tabs.
How to hide the searchview menu item for tab1 and tab2?

Comment: Why didn't you inflate your menu from inside fragment?

Comment: @IvanMilisavljevic because for two tabs menu items were same and only for third one it was different.

Comment: Same code is working with the latest android library. I think this was bug in earlier release.

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor for page changes and call invalidateOptions menu every time there is a change in a ViewPager

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1 || viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
                contactsSearchMenu.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                contactsSearchMenu.setVisible(false);
            }

            return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

Comment: How to set tags for fragments in viewpager?

Comment: So you are using ViewPager?

Comment: Yes , You can see my activity layout

Comment: Fragment f = mViewPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
        Fragment f1 = mViewPagerAdapter.getItem(1); I changed the code and rest the same which you said but still searchview item is visible for all three tabs.

Comment: Still searchview is visible in all three tabs plus same thing I am doing in fragments code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard. The `searchView` is a `View`, so you can use the Class `View` and it's properties and functions in `searchView`.

[Here is the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). Look for the `setVisibility` [function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)).

If you are looking for the menu item and not the `searchView` itself, you have to put the `setVisible(false)` in your `public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` function.

Comment: contactsSearchMenu.setVisible(false); this is set for tab1 and tab2

Comment: In this case, put the code in this function: onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) ; do it and say

Comment: still the same result

Comment: the final result is the same code as in tab 3??? Try to put on Tab3 false, only for testing. It should work on both cases.

Comment: If i don't add tab3 in the tab layout then other two menu items are visiible

Comment: But If i will add tab3 in the tab layout then only search view will be visible in all three tabs.

Comment: What if you want to reuse the SearchView action and not have it still be expanded when set visible again?